# UWP - Build a nice layout with XAML for all devices

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I wonder how can i build an XAML layout for an UWP app which will be nice on all devices. I made a layout composed by grids and stackpanels an when i launch it locally on my computer it's very nice at the smallest size (mobile).

[image]

When i resize it (tablet) it looks not very good but it pass

[image]

On desktop it's a shame ...

[image]

Grey parts are parts i would like to use on tablet and desktop, not used for the moment but i will put contents.

Then i tried the mobile size on a real device and surprise i can't see all the content. It's truncated just under the second row (Below the grey and blue button). I guess i must find a scrollview or someting like that and put my grid inside it.

But the most important question is how do you build your XAML to fit all the devices size ?? For example i would like squares as buttons but on tablet and desktop it looks like rectangle ... If i resize the grid to fit a square on tablet and desktop then i got big white spaces between rows on mobile. It gives me a headache ...

Have someone build such layout ? And can someone help me to understand how i can improve my layout ? Below the code i wrote ...

```
<Page
x:Class="RescueCode.UWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:RescueCode.UWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" MinHeight="800">
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Grid/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <AppBarButton Name="update" Icon="Download" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

<Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid" >

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="188*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="179*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="409*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="24"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


    <StackPanel x:Name="g1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="20" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="cameraButton" Click="cameraButton_Click" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#F15A22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="cameraImage" Source="Assets/scan.png" NineGrid="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="g2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="20" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="20"/>
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="searchButton" Click="searchButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Background="#f7a600" >
                <Image x:Name="searchImage" Source="Assets/search.png" NineGrid="0" Margin="20,20,20,20"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="g3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" >
        <TextBox Text="3"/>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel x:Name="g4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="20" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="aboutButton" Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0" Background="#6c7778"/>
        <Button x:Name="applicationButton" Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0" Background="#00ADEF"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="g5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Padding="20" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <TextBlock Text="Site" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="websiteButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Background="#fc0" Click="websiteButton_Click">
            <Image x:Name="websiteImage" Source="Assets/website.png" NineGrid="0" Margin="20,20,20,20"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="g6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" >
        <TextBox Text="6"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="g7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="20" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="s7" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="fejnfkjbshbcjhsdbvhdskjbcvjhskdnbckjscnkjdsncjnsdcjsdnbvjdjvsjhvlkenjlzsevnljhnjvklevbksvbjkdbnskjdjsdnvkjnkjvnkdjbkdjvbsdkjbvkdjvbkdjbskjvbekvbjdvb ." FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="g9" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="Gray" >
        <TextBox Text="9"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Thanks everyone for you help ! I appreciate :)

Comment: Sounds like something you should request on stackoverflow documentation.

Comment: Use the VisualStateManager as you got [replied to in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38713984/318501)

Answer (score 1):

As the comment in your previous question mentioned, `StackPanel` has indefinite height, and your accepted answer there can already solve your problem, with that solution, your layout on desktop should be for example like this:

[image]

Since your Buttons always fit the stretch their size to fit the containers, your buttons could be rectangle shape, but your images seem like all square shape. Since you asked this question again, my guess is that you want to keep your buttons be square shape?

If so, one method is that you can still use `VisualStateManager` to define size for each buttons in your layout as I suggested in your last question, and this time I provide another method, you can set a [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) outside of your `MainGrid` and move your `VisualStateManager` to the root control(now is the `ScrollViewer`) of this layout.

Your problem is actually that there is no enough height to hold your buttons' parents. the StackPanels, to make sure there has enough height, a `ScrollViewer` can help a lot:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="24"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="188*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="179*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="409*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--your layout without VisualStateManager-->

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works good but makes one problem which I consider as a good thing, it will trim the empty space in the end of your layout like this:

[image]